# Return null when closing JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a table that has a JDialog for add new record, When i click to add Button and want to add a new record and JDialog opened, I close JDialog window and it returns `null` for my all columns of my table rows.

This is my JDialog constructor:

```
public class AddBookDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

public AddBookDialog(JFrame owner) {
    super(owner, "Add New Book", true);
    initComponents();
    saveBtn.addActionListener(this);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == cancelBtn) dispose();
    else if (e.getSource() == saveBtn) saveAction();
        }
}
    public void saveAction() {
    if (nameTf.getText().trim().length() != 0) {
        if (!haveDigit(nameTf.getText().trim())) setBookName(nameTf.getText().trim());
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book Name have digit");
            return;
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Book Name");
        return;
    }
    if (isbnTf.getText().trim().length() != 0) {
        if (haveSpace(isbnTf.getText().trim()) || haveLetter(isbnTf.getText().trim())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Correct ISBN");
            return;
        }
        setIsbn(isbnTf.getText().trim());
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Book ISBN");
        return;
    }

    setBorrowStatus("No");
    setDate(dateGenerate());
    dispose();
}
```

I try to control this problem in my table GUI class:

```
public class BookPage_Admin extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
...

    public void addAction() {
    AddBookDialog dialog = new AddBookDialog(this);
    if (dialog.getBookName() != null && dialog.getIsbn() != null && dialog.getBorrowStatus() != null &&
            dialog.getDate() != null) {
        Object[] added = new Object[]{dialog.getBookID(), dialog.getBookName(), dialog.getIsbn(), dialog.getBorrowStatus(), dialog.getDate()};
        model.addRow(added);
     }
   }
}
```

But still when i close it, it returns `null` for my row.

How to prevent returning `null` when close it?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Comment: Verify that `model` does not shadow the table's model.

Comment: @trashgod Can you explain more?

Comment: Be sure the `model` to which you `addRow()` is the table's model and not a reference to a different model.

Comment: That `model` is a variable from my `defaultTableModel` extended class, And isn't a different model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case if no one will answer you:

When you initiate Dialog, aka `AddBookDialog dialog = new AddBookDialog(this);` you can override `ActionListener` on the Frame side like:

```
AddBookDialog dialog = new AddBookDialog(this);
dialog.setModal(true);

dialog.getSaveBtn().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      Object[] added = new Object[]{dialog.getBookID(), dialog.getBookName(), dialog.getIsbn(), dialog.getBorrowStatus(), dialog.getDate()};
      model.addRow(added);

            }
        });

// importent set visible after ActionListener!! 
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Hope it will help,

Comment: Well, Now where should i insert my `saveAction()` ?

Comment: you add listener to `Save` button, so just call it like `dialog.saveAction()` under  `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`